# Node.Js version 14 throw e; error for discord bots (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I forked a [Discord music bot](https://github.com/kabirsingh2004/A-Advance-Discord-Music-Bot-Like-Hydra-/tree/0230b574374d5236f3bd92f8c624ecf283602c28) from GitHub to [ReplIt](https://replit.com) and then I try to follow steps to run the bot successfully!

I use Node.JS v.14!

When I run the bot I receive following error:

```
/home/runner/A-Advance-Discord-Music-Bot-Like-Hydra-/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:121
        throw e;
        ^

Error: The module '/home/runner/A-Advance-Discord-Music-Bot-Like-Hydra-/node_modules/better-sqlite3/build/Release/better_sqlite3.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 88. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1151:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:996:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at bindings (/home/runner/A-Advance-Discord-Music-Bot-Like-Hydra-/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/A-Advance-Discord-Music-Bot-Like-Hydra-/node_modules/better-sqlite3/lib/database.js:9:24)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
exit status 1
```

And here is my `index.js` file:

```js
//Importing all needed Commands
const Discord = require("discord.js"); //this is the official discord.js wrapper for the Discord Api, which we use!
const colors = require("colors"); //this Package is used, to change the colors of our Console! (optional and doesnt effect performance)
const Enmap = require("enmap"); //this package is our Database! We will use it to save the data for ever!
const fs = require("fs"); //this package is for reading files and getting their inputs

//Creating the Discord.js Client for This Bot with some default settings ;) and with partials, so you can fetch OLD messages
const client = new Discord.Client({
  fetchAllMembers: false,
  restTimeOffset: 0,
  shards: "auto",
  restWsBridgetimeout: 100,
  disableEveryone: true,
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'],
  intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]
});

require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;
process.setMaxListeners(100);

//Loading files, with the client variable like Command Handler, Event Handler, ...
["clientvariables", "command", "events", "erelahandler", "requestreacts"].forEach(handler => {
    require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client);
});

//Each Database gets a own file and folder which is pretty handy!
client.premium = new Enmap({ name: "premium", dataDir: "./databases/premium" })
client.stats = new Enmap({ name: "stats", dataDir: "./databases/stats" })
client.settings = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/settings" })
client.setups = new Enmap({ name: "setups", dataDir: "./databases/setups" })
client.queuesaves = new Enmap({ name: "queuesaves", dataDir: "./databases/queuesaves", ensureProps: false})
client.modActions = new Enmap({ name: 'actions', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });
client.userProfiles = new Enmap({ name: 'userProfiles', dataDir: "./databases/warns" });

//login into the bot
client.login(require("./botconfig/config.json").token);
```

Can anyone tell me my problem?

**Sorry for my bad English**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error we need to completely repair our npm memory!

1. In the first step, we need to delete node_modules:

   `$ rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
2. And then clean up our npm memory:

   `$ npm cache clear --force`

   `$ npm cache clean --force`
3. And reinstall it so that it compiles in the new version!

   `npm install`

I think this can be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to force clean your npm cache and remove your `node_modules` and reinstall them again to compile them against a new node version, for the same you may use the following commands in your Console / Shell:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json && npm cache clear --force && npm cache clean --force && npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you updated the Node.js version, you can use `npm rebuild` to rebuild to the new version of Node.js then start the application, use only once the command not every time you start the applicatoin